# Getting attributes without opening the module

Tags: ibm-doors

Is there a way to get the attributes of a module without reading it?
I need to get that information for about 100 modules and it takes over 10 minutes if I have to read each module

I don't need to actually get the objects just the attributes available in the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModuleProperties should be faster. Try sth like this:

```
Item i = null
ModuleProperties mp = null
string sModuleAttribute = ""
string sError = ""
for i in project "/<myproject>" do {
    if (type i == "Formal") {
        sError = getProperties (moduleVersion module fullName i, mp)
        if (null sError) {
            for sModuleAttribute in mp do {
                print fullName i "\t" sModuleAttribute "\t" mp.sModuleAttribute "\n"
            }
        } else {print sError "\n"}
        delete mp
    }
}
```

If you are also interested in the existence of attribute definitions for Objects, this might help

```
Item i = null
ModuleProperties mp = null
AttrDef ad = null
string sError = ""
for i in folder "/<myproject>" do {
    if (type i == "Formal") {
        sError = getProperties (moduleVersion module fullName i, mp)
        if (null sError) {
            for ad in mp do {
                print fullName i "\t" ad.name "\t" ad.typeName "\t" ad.object "\t" ad.module  "\n"
            }
        } else {print sError}
        delete mp
    }
}
```

Comment: When we get sError? I mean in what occasions we get sError is not NULL?

Comment: I would think mainly when DOORS has no access to the ModuleVersion. When I created the snippet I made a mistake where I gave an invalid ModuleVersion and DOORS complained that such an object does not exist (the perm that we use here is `string getProperties (ModuleVersion, ModuleProperties&)` and there are several ways to create variables of type ModuleVersion). Other errors could be that (if the ModuleVersion refers to a baseline) that baseline does not exist. Or that you have no read access to the Module. Or that there is a database corruption, .... You will see what sError will tell you :)

Comment: Please note that I added a command to cleanup memory for the case that your script runs in a bigger context (`delete mp`), and that I used two different kinds of loops in my snippet. `for Item in Folder` will only loop over the items in one folder (non recursive), `for Item in Project` will loop over every item in the complete project, including items in subfolders and subprojects.

Comment: `ModuleProperties mp
ModuleVersion mv
string mname = "/Training Car Project/Marketing Requirements"

Baseline b = baseline(2,5,"")//I defined wrong baseline for Marketing Requirements here

string s
mv = moduleVersion(module mname, b)
string err = getProperties (mv, mp)
if (!null err){
print err "\n"
}` Instead of displaying error message, DOORS crashed. Where I made mistake?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @AshokAnumula I don't know, i tested your code and got the error messages `null Module parameter was passed into argument position 1` when `mname` points to a non existing module and `baseline '2.5' does not exist` for a non-existing baseline, but no DOORS crash. Perhaps you just need to restart DOORS? I use DOORS 9.7.2.2 for my tests.

Comment: I tried again. Same code crashing DOORS 9.5

Comment: DOORS 9.5 as in "DOORS 9.5.0.0, released 27 Nov 2012", as in "out of support since 2020-09-30" and as in "contains several vulnerabilities and bugs"? Yes, I can confirm that I get the same error in that version and advise to migrate to a newer version of DOORS ASAP.